# `tf.data.Dataset` runs on CPU, except of `PrefetchDataset`?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

After reading through the `tf.data` documentation ([here for TF 1.15](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)), related TF code (both Python and C++), I realized that most of it seems to run purely on CPU, except of `PrefetchDataset`.

Is that true?

The documentation for `prefetch_to_device` says:

> NOTE: Although the transformation creates a `tf.data.Dataset`, the
>   transformation must be the final `Dataset` in the input pipeline.

Which suggest that all other datasets cannot handle such a GPU-based dataset.

While looking through the code, there seems to be some internal datasets, e.g. `_CopyToDeviceDataset` and `_MapOnGpuDataset`, which might handle GPU datasets.

If I want to have my preprocessing (e.g. data augmentation, some other clever non-trivial stuff) on GPU, that means that I cannot use `tf.data`? (I also want to use graph mode, but not sure if that is relevant.)

Now I also found `_GeneratorDataset`. [That kernel also is defined on GPU](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/bbe150901badaf042ae66bd0dd6857aca2ac42fd/tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc#L226). So that means that if my `next_func` returns a tensor on GPU, it will always stay on GPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, `tf.data` currently does all of its processing on CPU. Usually this is desirable to avoid contending with the GPU, and because much preprocessing is easier to implement on the CPU. However, there isn't anything fundamentally preventing `tf.data` from doing processing on the GPU - it's just a matter of implementing such support. From the looks of it, [map_on_gpu](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/ops/prefetching_ops.py#L260) does offer a way to apply a map function on GPU, though `map_on_gpu` isn't yet exported in the public API. If you're interested in such functionality, please create a [Github Issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) describing your use case

To answer your last question, if you have a `_GeneratorDataset` which is placed on GPU, the tensors it produces will also be on GPU. However, you cannot apply additional dataset transformations other than `prefetch` because those dataset transformations don't have GPU implementations.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited the appropriate \_\_init__.py so I can use the private API, and map_on_gpu seem to be doing exactly what I want. I just want a 100% GPU utilization producer/consumer pipeline (where the CPU and GPU can run in parallel), which seems impossible to build without it. The documentation of tf.data is extremely confusing in that it seems to talk a lot about optimizing for this kind of parallelization without even supporting it on a single machine? I want tf.data to be a workaround for tensor evaluation without taking the python GIL.